# Safe to rely CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL instead of Location address?

Tags: php, url, curl, php-curl, get-headers

When recursively expanding an URL, is it safe to rely on the URL result using `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL)` other than the `Location` header (301/302 redirection)?

I found that the `location` URL might be relative, but the `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` is always absolute. Which one is better? I'm doing recursive expanding for a URL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` saves you some work as in the end you need to have FQDN anyway:

> Location = URI-reference
>
> The field value consists of a single URI-reference.  When it has
> the    form of a relative reference ([RFC3986], Section 4.2), the
> final    value is computed by resolving it against the effective
> request URI    ([RFC3986], Section 5).

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231

Comment: thanks, and how can I stop my recursion? currently, It won't continue if there's no `Location` header. what does `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` return if there's no redirection?